# How do I reduce package content on a custom install CD?

Tags: system-installation

I normally do all my installs via PXE server, but I'm building a custom CD for kvm installs that are not on the same vlan as my PXE server.  I would prefer this CD was as small as possible and it fetched packages from the network like netinstall mini.iso CD does, but netinstall doesn't mount /cdrom like the server install CD does.  I need the cdrom for preseed.

I've got my custom server install CD working, but it is still ~700MB.  Trying to modify "dists/lucid/main/binary-amd64/Packages.gz" gives me no love as it complains that I've got a corrupt Packages.gz no matter what I do.  I'd rather the preseeded mirror was used rather than CD once it gets the cdrom setup.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Start from an Ubuntu minimal CD, add essential packages via [UCK](http://uck.sourceforge.net/) and burn it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to also regenerate the Releases.gpg file. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

Comment: This shows me how to sign the Release file but it doesn't tell me how to deal with dependency hell.  I only want the required debs on the CD to get me to the point where it can retrieve everything else from a mirror.